# Copy full Form in Designer in valid way (Visual C# Net 2)

Tags: c#, winforms, duplicates, designer

I try to duplicate a form in my Designer with all the elements on it, that i have not to do the huge Job again of designing the full form again. I need only a few little changes on this form copy to do, so i do not want to design the same again from new.
If i click on the form "copy" and then do "paste" on my Project the full Project is destroyed forever and a lot of error Messages Pop up about the form copy. I had to throw my Project afterwards since there's no undo of that action possible. Since this was a huge loss of work I decided to ask the question:

**How do I valid copy/duplicate an existing form in the designer without errors afterwards appearing?**

Comment: Why don't you inherit that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should duplicate the form file, then change the class name in the copy in both the `.cs` and the `.Designer.cs` files.